# Getting question marks when I read from text file

Tags: java

So Im using FileReader to read files and when swedish letters appears it shows question marks instead of the letters, already tried to set the default encoding to utf-8 in eclipse and so on but I dont know why this happens.

```
                FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
                File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if(file == null) {
                    return;
                }
                String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();               
                FileReader inFile = new FileReader(fileName);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inFile);
                //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```

This is what I've tried thus far (including the commented out part), kinda at a dead end atm.

Comment: But you sure that the text file is encoded using UTF-8? It's popular, but not everyone will use it.

Comment: could you provide an example of what your trying to read?

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the file with `UTF-8` by overload constructor in `FileReader`

```
FileReader inFile = new FileReader(file, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

[Charset Oracle Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `UTF-8` does not include all characters you can try with `ISO-8859-1`

```
 FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
 File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
 if (file == null) {
     return;
 }
 String fileName = file.getAbsolutePath();
 FileReader inFile = new FileReader(fileName);
 //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inFile), "ISO-8859-1"));
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inFile), "UTF-8"));
 String line = null;

 line = bufRdr.readLine();
```

May be there is another issue with console won't support those characters

Comment: UTF8 *does* include "all" characters (using up to 3 bytes), much more than ISO-8859-1 does (which is limited to 1 byte). UTF8 just does not map characters between 128 and 255 to the same characters as ISO-8859-1 does. Blindly guessing the encoding may or may not work. Console may or may not support the characters, that is a good point (if OP looks at the output in a Windows console).